# How to bind XAML Command to View -or- Update DataGrid item(s) on modification without INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid in a Window with associated View(*.xaml.cs) and ViewModel that is successfully executing a bunch of functionality. However, functions that modify items instead of altering the collection do not update until a sort, resize, etc.

I've found a bunch of search results suggesting the solution is to make the item type implement INotifyPropertyChanged and add/subtract event handlers as appropriate for every item in the collection. I tried for a bit using those examples without success, but frankly it doesn't seem like a great option.

The item type is declared elsewhere in the app and is sharing the object instances with other modules, so I would like not to modify that class. It also seems like a poor design to tie the implementation of the DataGrid's ItemsSource to the item type within; the list container is already an ObservableCollection invoking OnPropertyChanged as needed already, so why should that not be sufficient?

I'm able to update via DataGrid.Items.Refresh() - which unfortunately does not seem to have an overload for specific items/properties instead of updating the entire list, but that's a minor issue - but only my View has a reference to the DataGrid itself (per MVVM), whereas the Command binding is in the ViewModel.

I would actually like to put those Command bindings in the View, and I don't understand why convention is to put those in the VM and thereby bypass the View during a UI event. For example, to delete items I can select them and either press Delete (KeyUp handler is in the View, which then passes selected items as a list to the VM) or select Delete in the context menu (Binding is to an ICommand in the VM, which routes to the same function invoked by the View). Why would it not be more desirable to bind both to the View's event handler (or two handlers both in the View)?

I've seen some results that use a RelativeSource for the Command binding to an ancestor of type UserControl...I've tried with type Window to try to bind to the View's method for naught. As of now my best option is to put a delegate event RefreshListItems on the VM and subscribe to it from the view with a function that invokes DataGrid.Items.Refresh().

This is workable, but in the interest of edification I wondered if anyone could tell me how to bind Command properties to the View (a Window) instead of the ViewModel, and/or how to notify the control bound to my ObservableCollection to refresh either specific or all items from the ViewModel without implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged scheme on every list item?

**Edit per mm8's suggestion:**

I tried your code for the ICommand in my view, but I get this error:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=SetService; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')`

That's with each of these attempts, with and without `CommandParameter`, bound to an `ICommand` of type either `RelayCommand` or `DelegateCommand`:

```
<MenuItem Header="Set Service" Command="{Binding SetService, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>

<MenuItem Header="Set Service" Command="{Binding SetService, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>

<MenuItem Header="Set Service" Command="{Binding SetService, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

**.xaml:**

```
<Window>
…
    <DataGrid x:Name="TheGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MessageItems}}" KeyUp="MessageList_KeyUp" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnWidth="Auto">
    …
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Set Service" Command="{Binding SetService, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid>
…
</Window>
```

**.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class TheGridView : Window
{
    TheGridViewModel _viewModel;
    public ICommand SetService; 

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public TheGridView(TheGridViewModel vm)
    {
        DataContext = _viewModel = vm;
        vm.RefreshListItems += () => TheGrid.Items.Refresh();

        InitializeComponent();
        Closing += Window_Closing;

        SetService = new RelayCommand(SetSvc);
    }

    private void SetSvc(object selectedItem)
    {
        // Doesn't get here
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your POCO classes loaded into your ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is workable, but in the interest of edification I wondered if anyone could tell me how to bind Command properties to the `View` (a `Window`) instead of the ViewModel?

There is nothing that stops you from defining `ICommand` properties in the code-behind of the view and bind to them like this (assuming your view is a `Window`):

```
Command="{Binding YourCommandProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
```

**Edit:**

A `ContextMenu` resides in its own visual tree but you should be able to bind to the parent window through the `Tag` property of the `DataGrid`, something like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TheGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MessageItems}}" KeyUp="MessageList_KeyUp" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnWidth="Auto">
    <DataGrid.Tag>
        <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" />
    </DataGrid.Tag>
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Set Service" Command="{Binding  PlacementTarget.Tag.SetService, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

> ...and/or how to notify the control bound to my `ObservableCollection` to refresh either specific or all items from the ViewModel without implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` scheme on every list item?

You can't do this unless you refresh the entire control (for example using `DataGrid.Items.Refresh()`). That's why you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

If you currently bind to some class that is shared across several modules and you don't want to modify this class, you could create a new client-specifc wrapper class that does implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and bind to this one instead of binding to the common class, e.g.:

```
public class Wrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly SharedModel _model;
    public Wrapper(SharedModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    private string _property;
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set { _property = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    //...
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Added code of my unsuccessful attempt at your example.

Comment: @Swavity: You didn't mention anyting about a ContextMenu...See my edited answer,

Comment: `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SetService' property not found on 'object' ''TheGridView' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.SetService; DataItem='ContextMenu' (Name=''); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')`


Attempted while exposing a public ICommand set to a RelayCommand instance as both a field and a property.

Comment: I'd forgotten to put a getter back in; it works now. Appreciate the help, mm8.